# Need suggestion on sharing constant values throughout my project

Tags: c++

I'm currently developing a game and using C++.
I need some constant values which must be globally available to all my project files. Currently the way i am handling this is i have a header file named Constants.h which declares everything `static const typedef name = value`.
This file is included in every project file that needs those values.

The problem i'm facing with the above is as my project increases in size so does the build time. I understand why this is happening and although when i first started my project seemed viable it has now became an issue.

Can you suggest me another way to handle something like this in my projects?
Thank you.

Comment: Are these constants not associated with particular units of your code (e.g. classes)? If not, you have some major coupling going on there.

Comment: No i don't think so unless i don't understand your question. Mostly those values are used in logic updates and are things like fixed positions or enums that need to be referenced everywhere

Comment: Does `Constants.h` include other headers ? Do `Constatnts.h` may be split ?

Comment: @Jarod42 no it does not include other header files

Comment: How long is the file ? I suspect it is an other part of the build which take time. Do you use forward declaration when possible ?

Comment: @Jarod42 200 lines by now and it keeps increasing as more values need to be globally available. And i am declaring everything the same time i define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining static variables, why not just *declare* them, and then define them in a source file?

So in the header file

```
extern const int some_global_const;
```

And in the source file

```
const int some_global_const = 1;
```

---

Another system which I have used before is to have some kind of property system, where you have a "map" of key-value pairs (often using e.g. `std::map` under the hood) where the key is a string, and the value is something that can be converted to any other type.

Then you can do something like `Config::get("some_global_const")` to get a property.

This can be done to set both compile-time properties, and to read properties during run-time.

Comment: why not just define them in every source file?

Comment: No OP define them in Header and include that file, you said declare them in header and then define them in source. Im asking why not define them in source file

Comment: @OmerObaid Your sentence makes absolutely no sense

Comment: @OmerObaid So you have top copy-paste the same definitions over multiple source files? What if you change one variable, and forget to paste it into one source file? What would happen then?

Comment: Your second suggestion i guess it requires some kind of object as the property system? I would like to avoid creating an object (if possible) to handle this. About you first suggestion please forgive my ignorance, would this method decrease the compile-time? And if so how would affect run-time? Or what are the drawbacks in general?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg With external linkage this wouldnt work: Multiple definitions

Comment: @Paranaix Pardon me english isn't my native language.

Comment: @Paranaix Well, I assumed they would be declared `static`, just like in the current header file.

Comment: I gave it a go and somewhat works. Actually the first time i declare something my first compile will have the same effects. After that if i want to edit the value it will only have to recompile the Constants.cpp file which is pretty nice. But right now my biggest issue is the enum migration. Can't extern typedefs. If i don't get any more answers soon i'll accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a game, I would suggest putting the global constants into a configuration file, reading it on startup and making them available in something like a property system.

This way, in the future you are very flexible and you can easily change and test different values without compiling at all, what is very important when your project starts to get really big.

Comment: This is really interesting and i would really say it's sort of a standard out there(just check your game directories). I wonder how this never crossed my mind. But still, i think your answer is missing. How would i get them available throughout my project efficiently?

Comment: I would use a configuration class with a static lookup function declared in a common header file. As this class will not change very often, there should be no compilation overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in a static class.

Globals.h

```
class Globals
{
public:
    static const int something;
};
```

Globals.cpp

```
#include "Globals.h"
const int Globals::something = 10;
```

Other source files:

```
#include "Globals.h"

void f()
{
    int x = Globals::something;
}
```